# Configure Kerberos auth for TFS 2013

Tags: windows, tfs, kerberos

I need to set up Kerberos authentication for TFS 2013. Is there any document that gives me steps to configure it? I have looked at the below mentioned links
http://blogs.like10.com/2012/05/09/using-friendly-dns-names-in-your-tfs-environment-with-kerberos-authentication-part-1/
http://blogs.like10.com/2012/06/21/using-friendly-dns-names-in-your-tfs-environment-with-kerberos-authentication-part-2/

My TFS still takes NTLM auth type every time. I would really appreciate if someone could send me links on how to configure Kerberos on Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kerberos is not a TFS capability but one of active directory. If you are able to get a nervous token on the TFS accounts with the delegated URL so in your SPN, then you only need to switch TFS over.

You might find the option in the console but i am getting that It is a setup option.

Run "tfsconfig.exe setup /uninstall:all" to undo your current configuration. Then when configuring select "advanced" and you should get an option for ntlm/kerberos.